# company-mode: no completions found

Tags: company-mode, doom, company

I am new to emacs (long-time vim user). Specifically, I am using [doom-emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs).

Doom is supposedly set up to use `company-mode` for auto completion, but I have not gotten it to work. I have the following source code:

```ruby
class CompleteUserBankruptcyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user)
    CompleteUserBankruptcy.call(user)
  end
end
```

If I type in `def perfo`, I would expect company to suggest `perform`. However, it does not suggest anything at all. If I manually trigger suggestions via `C-SPC`, it says "No completion found". Finally, if I run `company-diag` in the buffer, I get the following information:

```
Emacs 27.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0) of 2020-08-12 on builder10-14.porkrind.org
Company 0.9.13

company-backends: (company-capf company-yasnippet)

Used backend: company-yasnippet
Major mode: ruby-mode
Prefix: nil
Completions: none
```

I have no idea how to debug further. If it is any help, I have my personal configuration files [in this repo](https://github.com/stevenxl/doom), but I have not modified any company-mode related settings, so it should all be using the default from doom-emacs, which for company I believe are [located here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/tree/1456108d5bef89195b2b63f962e0ae9d24f4c652/modules/completion/company). Finally, I believe that the list of backends is not being set correctly in `ruby` major mode (and may be failing in other modes as well), given the references to company in this [file](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/1456108d5bef89195b2b63f962e0ae9d24f4c652/modules/lang/ruby/config.el).

Comment: In your repo, init.el file: you did not enabled ruby language - uncomment that line, save and in terminal ```doom sync```. Also, with the point on ```ruby``` word, press ```K``` to see the documentation - further configuration may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which completion backend Doom uses by default these days for Ruby (whether it's LSP or Robe), but the Troubleshooting section of `company/README.org` says this:

> For instance, go-mode requires guru to be installed on your system, and ruby-mode requires that you have a Robe server running (M-x robe-start).

Meaning, you need to have `robe` (the package) installed (perhaps it already is) and to type `M-x robe-start` to launch the background process. And to possibly deal with any errors you see if it fails to launch (e.g. run `bundle install`).

Yes, I'm also not sure why `company-robe` is not in the list of backend, but perhaps it will be added automatically as soon as the `robe` package is (auto)-loaded.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry - I feel like we are getting closer. I made sure that I am on the latest [commit ](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/tree/29b12de83e5f8ce76e9ff38549753c69bc507650) of doom's develop branch by running `doom upgrade`. However, I still don't see `robe-start`, and the instructions on the readme only say to run `gem install rubocop`.

Comment: Try installing the `robe` package. Or `lsp-mode`.

Comment: Ah - yes, I am definitely missing the `robe` package. If I run `doom-describe-package` for `robe`, I get the following: `    Package: robe
     Source: Not installed
    Modules: Declared by the following Doom modules:
             :lang ruby
    Configs: This package is configured in the following locations:
             modules/lang/ruby/config.el:38:(use-package! robe
`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix this the correct way, since it looks like `doom` should have installed `robe`.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help: I don't use Doom myself. Try https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/#getting-help

Comment: I switched to using `lsp-mode` instead. It looked like the `robe` package was not installed properly by Doom.There are instructions on how to enable `lsp-mode` in the `ruby` lang readme.